# Get currently selected line in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox` that contains a list of files.
I want to open a file when a user double clicks on it.

How do I get the currently selected line in C#?

Comment: Wouldn't a listbox make more sense for a "list of files"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [RichTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex.aspx). Pass in the [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx) property value from the text box.